# IsolatedStorageException in a windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I am trying to read a file not created in the application.

Here is the sample i tried :

```
string FileName = "stops.txt";
string FolderName = "data";
string FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderName, FileName);

IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

I throw a "isolatedstorageexception" : 
[link to exception](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/DllResourceIDs/Default.aspx?Version=4.0.50829.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=IsolatedStorage_Operation_ISFS)

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: [IsolatedStorage_Operation_ISFS]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.50829.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=IsolatedStorage_Operation_ISFS
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at HorairesCTS.MainPage.test()
   at HorairesCTS.MainPage..ctor()
```

Can someone help me to read this file ?

Thank you !

Comment: When you say "not created in the application" - what *did* create the file? If it's not created by your application, why would you expect it to be in the user store for the application?

Comment: Its a file that was copy/paste in the project, not created with isolatedstorage functions

Comment: I suspect it's not in isolated storage then - at least not in the user part of isolated storage. If it's in the project, you may be able to access it as a resource URL, or just embed it in the assembly.

Comment: Already tryed this : var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/HorairesCTS;data/stops.txt", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
string x = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); 
And i throw a NullReferenceException

Comment: Well I'd go back to working out why that's not working, rather than the isolated storage - because it doesn't sound like you'll find it there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to read a file that is included in your project, it won't be in the `IsolatedStorage`. You need to access it via `Application.GetResourceStream`.

Here is a sample code to read a local text file:

```
private string ReadTextFile(string filePath)
{
    var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative));
    Stream myFileStream = resourceStream.Stream;
    StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream);
    return myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Don't forget to set the `Build action` to `Content` on the properties of the file in Visual Studio.

```
ReadTextFile("data/stops.txt")
```

Comment: it works perfectly. I dont understand why it failed with this link : http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files But Thx for the sample !

Comment: It's because your file is not in the IsolatedStorage, it is in the Application Folder as you embed it with your app. The IsolatedStorage is where you store files generated at runtime (it is empty by default).

Answer (score 0):

If you wand to save a list of objects. You can do this:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream outStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyData.bin", FileMode.Create, myStore);
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<ClsUser>));

        ser.WriteObject(outStream, valutaTyperListe);
        outStream.Close();
```

Get the data:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (myStore.FileExists("MyData.bin"))
            {

                IsolatedStorageFileStream inStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyData.bin", FileMode.Open, myStore);

                DataContractSerializer Serializ = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<ClsUser>));
                myUserList = Serializ.ReadObject(inStream) as List<ClsUser>;
                inStream.Close();
            }
```

And the Class look like this, remember to to add "using System.Runtime.Serialization;":

```
[DataContract]
public class ClsUser
{
    string name;
    string lastname;

    public ClsUser(string name, string lastname)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

     [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

     [DataMember]
    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value; }
    }
}
```